# mysql group by and take specific record from right join table

Tags: mysql, join

I have database with following data structure with sample data. Each company have multiple members. The relationship is in the company_member table. Please note only required fields I have given below.

**company**

```
id   title
1    company-1
2    company-2
```

**company_member**

```
companyid  memberid
1          1
1          2
1          3
2          4
2          5
2          6
```

**member**

```
id   firstname  member_type_id
1    Name-1     2
2    Name-2     3
3    Name-3     3
4    Name-4     3
5    Name-5     2
6    Name-6     1
```

**member_type**

```
id   user_level
1    0
2    1
3    2
```

I want list of **unique** companies with one member from each. But the member should be the **lowest** user_level **within** the company. i.e, following result should come;

**result**

```
companyid  company_title  memberid  member_name  user_level
1          company-1      1         Name-1       1
2          company-2      6         Name-6       0
```

I want to know how to get one member with lowest user level among the same company.

Comment: Why don't you just store the user_level in the member table?

Comment: You are correct. But these tables extracted from an existing large-scale system. So there are other fields as well. By normalization or some other reason, the user_level is in member_type table, since it is related to some other tables.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit complicated one, however this is one way of doing it using `not exists`, for bigger tables its wise to use `not exits` since using pivot tables it will not use index.

```
select
c.id,
c.title,
m.id as member_id,
m.firstname,
mt.user_level
from company_member_map cmp
join company c on c.id = cmp.companyid
join member m on m.id = cmp.memberid
join member_type mt on mt.id = m.member_type_id
where not exists
(
  select 1 from company_member_map t1 
  join member t2 on t2.id = t1.memberid
  join member_type t3 on t3.id = t2.member_type_id
  where
  t1.companyid = cmp.companyid
  and t3.user_level < mt.user_level
)
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90ad59/21)**

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found solution:

```
select c.id companyid, c.title company_title, m.firstname member_name, mt.user_level
from company c
inner join company_member cm on cm.companyid = c.id
inner join member m on m.id = cm.memberid
inner join member_type mt on mt.id = m.member_type_id
inner join 
    (select c1.id companyid, mt1.user_level
        from company c1
        join company_member cm1 on cm1.companyid = c1.id
        join member m1 on m1.id = cm1.memberid
        join member_type mt1 on mt1.id = m1.member_type_id
        group by c1.id,m1.id
        order by user_level asc
    ) sq on c.id = sq.companyid and sq.user_level = mt.user_level
group by c.id;
```

Correct this, if anyone have better solution or simplified solution.

**[Check this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f4c8)**

Comment: This solution relies on an undocumented hack (unless you count the comments section of the relevant page in the manual). A better (and, if anything, faster) alternative would be to go with the uncorrelated subquery solution provided in the manual (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Can you please explain the "undocumented hack"?

Comment: I'd rather not. :-( Theoretically, MySQL cannot guarantee that the rows in the subquery will be returned to the superquery in the order you envisage. When grouping, the processor is (in theory) free to pick any of the available 'user_level's. In practice, it always picks the right one, and it's fine, but that's a different matter.

Comment: Thanks. Won't the order by user_level in subquery solve the issue? i.e returns the lowest user_level first so that, when we join it will use the first record to merge?

Comment: It does - but only by luck rather than skill! As I say, there's a mismatch between theory and practice - one that heppens to work in your favour. The theory says, when grouping, the processor is able to take any row. In practice, it always takes the first one.

Comment: Thanks got it. How about Abhik Chakraborty's solution above?

Comment: It's got a group by clause and no aggregating functions, so I think we know what I'm going to think about that ;-)

Comment: Correct. I agree with what you said - by luck